# Is there a way to add %APPDATA% to the Log4Net configuration path in AssemblyInfo.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, relative-path

I am configuring log4net to use a separate configuration file. This can be done by adding the following line in your AssemblyInfo.cs file.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

This location is relative to the program directory, yet I want it in a user's APPDATA folder. Something like:

```
ConfigFile = @"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config"
```

The problem is that this is not a relative path, i.e., a different usernames are not supported etc. What I really want is the following:

```
ConfigFile = @"%APPDATA%\MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config"
```

This of course does not work. I was hoping that this might fix it:

```
ConfigFile = @"${APPDATA}\MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config"
```

or this:

```
ConfigFile = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    @"MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config")
```

No luck. The two first just thinks it is part of a relative path, the latter is refused since it is in AssemblyInfo:

> Error 1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type  C:\Source\ ... \Tools\Logging\Logging\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs    39  56  Logging

Do I have to configure the application to use the custom path at startup? I really don't want to, because I want the code to be as agnostic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up performing the configuration at startup. In the implementation of my logging facade I just said:

```
class Log4NetLogger : ILogger
{
    public Log4NetLogger(...)
    {
        if (!m_Configured){
            string configFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config");
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(configFile));
            m_Configured = true;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess I shouldn't hard code the "MyApplication\Logging\Log4Net.config" path either.